# Laravel check session on every page

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4 for my website, and would like to check on every page load if user has seen a popup, and if not - show the popup to the user.

I don't want to do that in every controller, is there a place where can I put the code, so it's checked before every page is loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a filter to check if the popup is shown.

```
// app/filters.php

Route::filter('popup.shown', function()
{
    // Your check logic here
});
```

Then, you could use that filter in your routes, controllers or a base controller which you could extend to have this functionality:

```
class PopupController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('popup.shown');
    }

}
```

Then, extend this controller:

```
class MyController extends PopupController {

    public funcion getIndex()
    {
        // this will run the `popup.shown` filter 
    }

}
```

You can read more about `beforeFilter()` here:

- http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-filters

---

Another approach would be to use the [`App::before()`](http://laravel.com/docs/lifecycle#application-events) event, so the check would be done on every request. However, **I don't recommend this one as it's not flexible** and you will have to modify it soon or later.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this via a view/template style. Although if you use a lot of templates that don't show this popup then maybe the `filter` method suggested by Manuel Pedrera is best.

In `global.php` or some bootstrap file you can set a view variable that is injected automatically. http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views

```
// Perform popup logic
View::share('showPopup', $logicResult);
```

And then in the various layouts you want to include this popup you can check for the variable within the view. http://laravel.com/docs/templates

```
@if ($showPopup)
<div class="popup">Popup</div>
@endif
```

The advantage of this is that you do not have to include the variable to show/hide the popup for every `View::make()` call.